# Как удалить все нарисованые элементы с панели

Tags: java, swing

Есть тетрис, пытаюсь седалть рестарт игры, при нажатии кнопки нужно очистить панель и чтобы игра началась заново, не могу понять как это правильно сделать, вот

```
`   class Canvas extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            for (int x = 0; x < FIELD_WIDTH; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < FIELD_HEIGHT; y++) {
                    if (mine[y][x] > 0) {
                        g.setColor(new Color(mine[y][x]));
                        g.fill3DRect(x*BLOCK_SIZE+1, y*BLOCK_SIZE+1, BLOCK_SIZE-1, BLOCK_SIZE-1, true);
                    }
                }
            if (gameOver) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                for (int y = 0; y < GAME_OVER_MSG.length; y++)
                    for (int x = 0; x < GAME_OVER_MSG[y].length; x++)
                        if (GAME_OVER_MSG[y][x] == 1) g.fill3DRect(x*11+18, y*11+160, 10, 10, true);
            } else
                figure.paint(g);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: И в чем проблема? Цепляете обработчик кнопки и вперед

Comment: m1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                

            }
        }); Каким образом?

Comment: я так понимаю у вас двумерный массив отвечает за поле правильно?

Comment: в обработчике обнулите массив поля. как у вас реализована логика обновления экрана?

Comment: Делать это в рисовалке кажется неосуществимым.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте положить Вашу панель Canvas на другую панель

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p.add(new Canvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

а когда надо очистить с панели p удалите все

```
p.removeAll();
```

и добавьте новую свою панель

```
p.add(new Canvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```